# How to convert "" to NULL in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm with a problem in PostgreSQL. I need to do something like this:

```
select * from single_occurrences
where 
age::int4 > 29
```

And I got this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
```

The field age is a text field. How can I convert all the "" values to NULL values?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM single_occurrences
 WHERE CASE WHEN age="" THEN NULL ELSE age::int4 END > 29
```

Comment: Unless you need to store the age of "3 months" while your at it consider changing the data type to an integer.

Comment: Or use interval while you're at it.

Comment: Surely those should be single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE single_occurrences SET age=NULL WHERE age="";